# How to read Version & Build in Xcode from General/Targets in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, version, plist, target

in my first app (I wrote in SwiftUI) I want to add a Button to send me a mail for feedback, bugs, ...
The button works perfect, but I want to add in this mail the current version and build of my app. Its showed in `General/Targets/Identity`. But i can't find a way to do this.

```
Button(action: {
    if let url = URL(string: "mailto:mail@mymailadress.com?subject=MyApp%20Feedback&body=Hallo,%3Cbr%3Ei%20will%20tell%20you%20something%20about%20this%20app:%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3EVersion:%20\(AppVersionBuild)"){
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } 
}) {
    HStack{
        Image(systemName: "envelope")
        Text("send a mail to mail@mymailadress.com")
    }
    .padding(10)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("GradientStart"), Color("GradientEnd")]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
    .cornerRadius(10, antialiased: false)
    .shadow(radius: 10)
}
```

Any idea how to get the version into the mail body (variable e.g. `AppVersionBuild`)?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function that returns the version and build number

```
func versionAndBuildNumber() -> String {
    let versionNumber = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
    let buildNumber = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
    if let versionNumber = versionNumber, let buildNumber = buildNumber {
        return "\(versionNumber) (\(buildNumber))"
    } else if let versionNumber = versionNumber {
        return versionNumber
    } else if let buildNumber = buildNumber {
        return buildNumber
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

and replace `\(AppVersionBuild)` with the following `\(versionAndBuildNumber())`